# Delete last node, or only node from a Linked List in Java.

Tags: java, linked-list

I am unable to get my program to delete the last node or only node in my linked list. It will delete any other node. This program allows the user to enter integers and delete them.  Thanks in advance for your help.

```
// This method finds the value requested in the Linked List.

public Node find(Node head, Comparable value2){
    if (head == null ) 
        {
            System.out.println("The list is empty");
            return null;
        }

    Node pointer = head;
        while (pointer != null)
        {
            if (pointer.data.compareTo(value2)>=0)
                {
                    Node delNode = pointer;
                    System.out.print("Found it. Deleting " + delNode.data + "\n");
                    return delNode;

                }
            pointer = pointer.next;
        }

        return null;    
}



// This method deletes a given value from the linked list. 

public void delete(Node head, Comparable value2){
     Node delNode;
     delNode = find(head, value2);
     if (delNode== null)
     {
         System.out.println("The value: " + value2 + " does not exist");
         print(head);

     }

     else
         {
         if (delNode.next == null)
         {
             System.out.println("Trying to delete last");
             delNode = null;
             print(head);
         }
         else{
             delNode.data = delNode.next.data;
             Node temp = delNode.next.next;
             delNode.next = null;
             delNode.next = temp;   
             print(head);
         }        
         }    
     return;
}
```

I thought that if (delNode.next== null) {delNode = null} would do it?

Comment: I fear you're having some pass-by-reference/pass-by-value issues here.  What behaviour were you expecting that you don't see, or what unexpected behaviour are you encountering?  How did you expect 'deleting' to work in this case?

Comment: `delNode` is a local variable. You can assign to it what you want, this will not affect the object's state. You probably want to update some fields instead.

Comment: is it a singly linked list ?

Comment: The method find will locate the correct node to delete every time. The method delete will only delete nodes that aren't the first or the last node even though find correctly identified the node.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to delete a node, you should have a reference to the node *before* the one you want to delete, say `beforeNode`, and set

```
beforeNode.next = beforeNode.next.next;
```

(Think about special cases like deleting the last element.)

See [Java Linked List search and delete method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13638289/java-linked-list-search-and-delete-method)

Please note that in the sequence

```
         delNode.next = null;
         delNode.next = temp;
```

The first line is useless.

Comment: In the case of only one node left find will return the correct one, and I can't set a before.                                                                  if (delNode.next == null)
         {
             System.out.println("Trying to delete last");
             delNode = null;
             print(head);
         }  // delNode = null should set only remaining node to null?

Comment: As you have probably modified the `find` method to `findTheNodeBefore` semantics, this method performs a special task you probably nedd nowhere else. I would suggest merging the two methods (`find`aka `findTheNodeBefore` and `delete`) into one. I suppose the new method won't be longer than a single one of yours - this is because of currently doing some `null` checks twice.

Answer (score 1):

You current delete operation effectively works by copying the next node into the current node and then deletes the next node, making it look like you deleted the current node. This is fine until there is no next node, as you have discovered.

The reason the following doesn't work

```
     if (delNode.next == null)
     {
         System.out.println("Trying to delete last");
         delNode = null;
         print(head);
     }
```

is that delNode is just a local variable, setting delNode to null doesn't affect anything outside of delete().

If you want to delete the last node from the list, you need to set the next pointer in the second last element to null. Therefor it is insufficient for find() to simply return the element you wish to delete -- you need the *previous* element.

Pseudocode for delete(data) should be (untested):

```
if head == null
    return
if head.data == data
    head = head.next
    return
previous = find_previous(data)
if previous == null
    return
previous.next = previous.next.next
```

Comment: you should better change the last line of your code with that: `Node delNode = previous.next; previous.next = previous.next.next; delNode.next = null; delNode = null;` in order not to have memory leak.

Comment: No there is not any memory leak. Yes the deleted node has nothing referring to it, but for that reason the garbage collector will clean it up. It is not necessary that the deleted node refer to nothing for it become eligible for  garbage collection.