# Deleting node in linklist java

Tags: java

I am to write a menu driven program that either accepts words and their meanings, or displays the list of words in lexicographical order (i.e. as in a dictionary). 
One method I have to write is a delete method. The assignment is based on the basic properties of linkedlist. We're not actually using the linkedlist class. 
This is what i have so far:

```
public String delete(String a) {
    boolean found = false;
    WordNode aux = list;
    WordNode back = null;
    String deleted = "";

    while (aux != null && !found) {

        if (a.equalsIgnoreCase(aux.getAll().getWord())) {
            deleted = deleted + aux.getAll().getWord();

            back = aux.next;

            aux = null;

            found = true;
        } else {

            back = aux;
            aux = aux.next;

        }

    }
    return deleted;
}
```

But whenever I call the delete method in my main class and then call my toString, the list is intact. The deleted words are still in the list.

Comment: I don't see any actual deletion going on!

Comment: Do you want to remove String a from list ? If so, what is the deleted used for ?  and as @ Robert Moskal pointed out, where is the deletion ?

Comment: The variable `found` isn't required and is redundant.

Comment: I think you might find help here too : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13638289/java-linked-list-search-and-delete-method

Comment: Thank you everyone! Quinn linked me to what i was looking for.
You were right Robert, seems like i wasnt removing any node from the list.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All you have to do is change the line (it's line #12, I think)

```
back = aux.next;
```

to

```
if (back == null)
  list.next = aux.next;
else
  back.next = aux.next;
```

Answer (score 1):

Maybe something like this?

```
public String delete(String a) {
    WordNode aux = list;
    WordNode back = null;        

    while (aux != null) {

      if (a.equalsIgnoreCase(aux.getAll().getWord())) {

        if (back != null) {
            //change the pointer from the previous node to the one after the deleted one
            back.next = aux.next;
        } else {
            //first node was found, so modify list to point his successor as the new head
            list = aux.next; 
        }
        return a;
      } else {
        back = aux;
        aux = aux.next;
      }

   }
   return ""; //no node was found
}
```

This should conform to your contract, but I would consider passing list as an argument and returning a pointer to the head.